# TypeScript dynamic imports

Tags: typescript, dynamic, import

I would like to ask if it is possible to use custom Promise to load the module instead of immediately resolving promise used by typescript.

If I have

```
function test() {
   const m: any = import("./test");
   console.log(m);
}
```

tsc transpiles to immediately (almost ;)) resolving Promise which calls the require, something like:

```
function test() {
   m = Promise.resolve().then(() => require("..."));
   console.log(m);
}
```

which actually works well when the module (or better said module bundle) is loaded from HTML script tag, but I want to use custom lazy loader returning the Promise and resolving it when the module (bundle) will be loaded by custom loader later in the application life cycle (basically when it will be needed - not when html loads) then use the require to provide specific module from the loaded module bundle.

Is this achievable with TS or do I need to use different approach (i.e. custom import function)? I would prefer TS way.

target: "esnext", module: "commonjs"

> EDIT (ANSWER):

first of all, my thinking was bad. The

```
function timer(): Promise<void> {
   return new Promise<void>((resolve: () => void) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
   });
}

let p = Promise.resolve().then(async() => { await timer(); } )
```

gets resolved when .then callback finishes. Not before it. So it is not immediately resolving promise and in previously mentioned case it gets resolved once the require function returns. I didn't know that so I was confused a little bit.

Out of that, its not possible to use dynamic imports without some bundler or post-compiler such as babel or webpack when the TSC module is set to "commonjs". When babel or webpack is used the dynamic import can be replaced with another loader/resolver than require in order to load the script asynchronously, execute and resolve a module from it. I didn't test in node, it could work out of the box without need of additional build tools.

With TSC module "esnext" the import keyword is kept in the code by TSC and it can be used directly in the environment where it is supported.

Comment: You need to use module type as "esnext" instead of "commonjs".

Comment: Ye, I have figured it out already, thanks. Its not useful for me anyway as I want to pack modules together.

Comment: But still I don't get why typescript generates Promise.resolve(). Its useless until packer replaces it with custom thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ugly solution. Use "eval". Typescript cannot compile your code in a string.